# jQuery unbinding a plugin event

Tags: jquery, binding

I've never needed to 'bind' or 'unbind' anything before so I'm getting confused because I can't find an example that directly relates to what I want to do.

There is a plugin that scrolls a div when you get to a certain point at a page [here](http://blog.echoenduring.com/wp-content/uploads/demos/echo_ContainedStickyScroll/) - you've all seen this kind of thing, right?

But **I only want the plugin to fire when the window is a certain width**, and then 'unfire' / unbind if the window is below that width again e.g....

(by the way #contact-form is the container I'm scrolling which contains, you guessed it, a contact form)

```
function contactForm() {
    windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if (windowWidth >= 1024) {
        jQuery('#contact-form').containedStickyScroll();
    } else {
        jQuery('#contact-form').unbind(); // I don't want the plugin to fire
    }
};    


// Standard stuff...

$(document).ready(function() {
    contactForm();
});

$(window).resize(function() {   
    contactForm();
});
```

This contained sticky scroll function looks like this:

```
  $.fn.containedStickyScroll = function( options ) {

    var defaults = {  
        oSelector : this.selector,
        unstick : true,
        easing: 'linear',
        duration: 500,
        queue: false,
        closeChar: '^',
        closeTop: 0,
        closeRight: 0  
    }  

    var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);

    if(options.unstick == true){  
        this.css('position','relative');
        this.append('<a class="scrollFixIt">' + options.closeChar + '</a>');
        jQuery(options.oSelector + ' .scrollFixIt').css('position','absolute');
        jQuery(options.oSelector + ' .scrollFixIt').css('top',options.closeTop + 'px');
        jQuery(options.oSelector + ' .scrollFixIt').css('right',options.closeTop + 'px');
        jQuery(options.oSelector + ' .scrollFixIt').css('cursor','pointer');
        jQuery(options.oSelector + ' .scrollFixIt').click(function() {
            getObject = options.oSelector;
            jQuery(getObject).animate({ top: "0px" },
                { queue: options.queue, easing: options.easing, duration: options.duration });
            jQuery(window).unbind();
            jQuery('.scrollFixIt').remove();
        });
    } 
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        getObject = options.oSelector;
        if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > (jQuery(getObject).parent().offset().top) &&
           (jQuery(getObject).parent().height() + jQuery(getObject).parent().position().top - 30) > (jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(getObject).height())){
            jQuery(getObject).animate({ top: (jQuery(window).scrollTop() - jQuery(getObject).parent().offset().top) + "px" }, 
            { queue: options.queue, easing: options.easing, duration: options.duration });
        }
        else if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() < (jQuery(getObject).parent().offset().top)){
            jQuery(getObject).animate({ top: "0px" },
            { queue: options.queue, easing: options.easing, duration: options.duration });
        }
    });
```

};

Comment: This is really hard to answer without knowing more about the `containedStickyScroll()` function, but you could just try on() and off(), and have a look at the [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or here on SO to see how they work.

Comment: I did have a look at that, but I don't understand how I would slot it into my code, since it keeps going on about click events etc. $("#dataTable tbody tr").on("click", function(event){
 alert($(this).text());
});

Can you give me an example of how I might try it?

Comment: Sure, something like `$(window).on('resize', contactForm);` and `$(window).off('resize', contactForm);`, place those within an if/else statement with the window with, and see if that works ?

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle for us to play around with?

Comment: I did try, but for some reason it doesn't work in JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/rYdHR/1/

Here is the demo page though - http://blog.echoenduring.com/wp-content/uploads/demos/echo_ContainedStickyScroll/

Comment: Fyi, it makes no sense at all to write `jQuery` if you sometimes use `$` anyway. However, to ensure maximum compatibility I'd suggest wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);` and only use `$` inside that block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin `containedStickyScroll` is not written very well, because it has no remove handler.

That leaves you with 3 options:

1. Fork the plugin.

   ```
   $.fn.containedStickyScroll = function( options ) {

      return this.each(function() {

      var self = this;

      function remove() {
           getObject = options.oSelector;
           jQuery(getObject).animate({ top: "0px" }, { queue: options.queue, easing: options.easing, duration: options.duration });
           jQuery(window).unbind("scroll", $self.data("containedStickyScroll").scrollHandler);
           jQuery('.scrollFixIt').remove();

           $(self).data("containedStickyScroll", false);
      }

       if (options == "remove") {
           remove();
           return;
       }

       // Make sure that this is only done once.
       if (this.data("containedStickyScroll"))
           return;

       var defaults = {  
           oSelector : this.selector,
           unstick : true,
           easing: 'linear',
           duration: 500,
           queue: false,
           closeChar: '^',
           closeTop: 0,
           closeRight: 0  
       }  

       var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);

       if(options.unstick == true){  
           $(this).css('position','relative');
           $(this).append('<a class="scrollFixIt">' + options.closeChar + '</a>');
           jQuery(options.oSelector + ' .scrollFixIt').css('position','absolute');
           jQuery(options.oSelector + ' .scrollFixIt').css('top',options.closeTop + 'px');
           jQuery(options.oSelector + ' .scrollFixIt').css('right',options.closeTop + 'px');
           jQuery(options.oSelector + ' .scrollFixIt').css('cursor','pointer');
           jQuery(options.oSelector + ' .scrollFixIt').click(remove);
       } 

       options.scrollHandler = function () {
           getObject = options.oSelector;
           if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > (jQuery(getObject).parent().offset().top) &&
              (jQuery(getObject).parent().height() + jQuery(getObject).parent().position().top - 30) > (jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(getObject).height())){
               jQuery(getObject).animate({ top: (jQuery(window).scrollTop() - jQuery(getObject).parent().offset().top) + "px" }, 
               { queue: options.queue, easing: options.easing, duration: options.duration });
           }
           else if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() < (jQuery(getObject).parent().offset().top)){
               jQuery(getObject).animate({ top: "0px" },
               { queue: options.queue, easing: options.easing, duration: options.duration });
           }
       };

       jQuery(window).scroll(options.scrollHandler);

       $(this).data("containedStickyScroll", options);
   };};
   ```

   Now you can do this:

   ```
   (function($) {

       function contactForm() {
           windowWidth = $(window).width();
           if (windowWidth >= 1024)
               $('#contact-form').containedStickyScroll();
           else
               $('#contact-form').containedStickyScroll("remove");
       };    

       // Standard stuff...

       $(document).ready(contactForm);

       $(window).resize(contactForm);

   })(jQuery);
   ```

   I have also removed a terrible practice of unbinding all event handlers from the window object, which is even worse than option 2.
2. Workaround the problem by removing all event handlers with unbind (including those that are not created by that plugin).

   Not really an option, because the scroll event handler is on the `window` object and it is very likely that other plugins etc may use the same event handler.

   ```
   $(window).unbind("scroll");
   ```
3. Reset the entire element on the DOM.

   ```
   (function() {

       var hasContactForm = false,
           $contactForm = $("#contact-form").clone();

       function contactForm() {
           windowWidth = $(window).width();
           if (!hasContactForm && windowWidth >= 1024) {
               hasContactForm = true;
               jQuery('#contact-form').containedStickyScroll();
           } else if (hasContactForm && windowWidth < 1024)
               hasContactForm = false;
               $('#contact-form').replaceWith($contactForm);
           }
       };    

       // Standard stuff...

       $(document).ready(contactForm);

       $(window).resize(contactForm);

   })();
   ```

   This may not be a viable solution either because it will also reset any of the users input. However you can add extra logic to carry the user input into the restored contact form.

Considering the many downsides of each option, I would strongly suggest to either find a better plugin, or write your own. Otherwise option 1 is probably the best (if it works).

Comment: I think I will try to write my own! This is getting way too complicated for something that should be simple - thanks for your advice and work though :-)

Comment: @SparrwHawk are you sure that you have added the duplicate `hasCOntactForm` check properly to ensure that the scroll even is not registered more than once?

Comment: I am thinking actually, this should be simple, because if you click the little ^ in the demo http://blog.echoenduring.com/wp-content/uploads/demos/echo_ContainedStickyScroll/ - this releases it. Can't we just simulate this?

Comment: @SparwHawk, but what it does is option 2, which imo is the worst one.

Comment: Option 1 should work, you just need to be sure that you do not call the plugin more than once before removing it again.

Comment: I've added some extra edits to option 1. For one I improved the way it removes it self on the click handler and I have added logic to prevent the plugin from executing more than once. on the same object.

Comment: Hey I've accepted your answer because it's very thorough and has given me advice about the (window).unbind problem, but to be honest, I couldn't get your option 1 to work, not sure why :-(. I'm too much of a jQuery noob to debug it. I managed to get it working with the unbind event. Even though you've made me aware of the limitations, I think it's an OK option for me for the site / page I'm working on. I'll be aware that it may conflict with other plugins though. For anyone else wondering, here is the code that worked for me http://pastebin.com/EaiVKn09

Thanks for your help @d_inevitable

Comment: @SparrwHawk thanks for accepting my answer. I've one more edit in the hope to get 1. working. The plugin itself make sure to not apply itself again on an option and I removed the check on the outside through the flag, which might have been the problem. Care to try it out?